# Generic Singleton in Java

Tags: java, generics, singleton

Why does the following code throws *java.lang.InstantiationException: generics.SingletonFoo$A*?

```
public class SingletonFoo {
    private static Object _tn;

    public static <T> T instance(Class<T> t) {
        if (_tn != null) {
            return (T) _tn;
        }
        try {
            _tn = t.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (T) _tn;
    }


    private class A{
        public A() {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SingletonFoo.instance(A.class));
    }
}
```

Is it related to type erasure somehow and it's not possible to create generic singleton in Java?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace instead of only the exception

Comment: Singleton is not a good pattern for anyone to use.  Google has a tool to identify them in their applications so they can be removed.  Maybe you shouldn't be putting effort into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here A is not static class. Which means it contains a reference to the containing SingletonFoo (implicitly), which means you likely can't instantiate it via newInstance.

try to make it static or  move it out of the class it if it doesn't need to be inner class.

**Solution 1 : make A a static member class**

```
private static class A{
        public A() {
        }
    }
```

**Soution 2:make it outside**

```
public class SingletonFoo {
    private static Object _tn;

    public static <T> T instance(Class<T> t) {
        if (_tn != null) {
            return (T) _tn;
        }
        try {
            _tn = t.newInstance();
            ;
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (T) _tn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SingletonFoo.instance(A.class));
    }

}

class A {
    public A() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Class A is inner class

Comment: sory it was typo, not inner need to be static

Comment: @JekinKalariya please change **make inner class static** to **make `A` a static nested class**

Comment: @JekinKalariya Thanks a lot. Though i think, solution 1, is less relevant. As the goal is return instance of the generic argument, while the solution returns class.

Comment: no dear it will also return instance of generic argument beacuse we pass  class name in class.forname

Comment: @JekinKalariya it returns instance of the class object not the instance of the class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Comment: @JekinKalariya I'll mark it as accepted if u remove the first solution. It's just not correct.